# On button click check which radio button selected in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, angular5, angular4-forms

I have two radio button and one button and on selection of radio button which I want to hide show div in angular 4. Here is My code [My Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2bn2dy). After selecting radio button then on click of button show hide div. Please help.

```
<div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadio1" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label border rounded px-5 py-2 mt-3 shadow-sm w-100" for="customRadio1">
  <span class="font-weight-bold">Radio Button 1</span>
  </label>
</div>
<div class="custom-control custom-radio">
  <input type="radio" id="customRadio2" name="customRadio" class="custom-control-input">
  <label class="custom-control-label border rounded px-5 py-2 mt-3 shadow-sm w-100" for="customRadio2">
  <span class="font-weight-bold">Radio Button 2</span>
</label>
</div>

<button>Show Content</button>
</div>


<div style="display:none;">
Radio Button 1 Content
</div>
<div style="display:none;">
Radio Button 2 Content
</div>
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? can you please add any attempts made?

Comment: I am new to angular 4 I have written this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `[(ngModel)]` for this.

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/on-button-click-check-which-radio-button-selected-in-angular-4?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

```
<div *ngIf="showcontent=='radio1'">
Radio Button 1 Content
</div>
<div *ngIf="showcontent=='radio2'">
Radio Button 2 Content
</div>
```

Comment: Im not sure that this will actually work to be honest explain your thought process

Comment: that just ignored the button

Comment: Thanks but this is on only radio button click. I want to user select radio button then click on "show content" button then content will show. Can u please help